# Thunderbird agenda native system notification?

Tags: notifications, calendar, system-tray, thunderbird, agenda

I've been looking for an answer to this for weeks and figured I might just ask the question directly.

I'm using Thunderbird 102.6.1 on Windows 10. I'm looking to replace the "standard" Thunderbird agenda popups (see screenshot below) with a "native" system notification such as for Windows 10 Calendar (see 2nd screenshot below). This is mainly because the TB agenda popup steals focus from other apps and I often end up typing on that window instead of the one I was previously writing on, which is frustrating.

I know this is possible for email notifications and I've already enabled that in the TB options, however I couldn't find the equivalent for agenda alerts.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Cheers

[image: TB agenda popup window]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here. The popup is called “reminder” while the native notification is called “notification” in Thunderbird settings.

So you should uncheck “Show reminders” option, and ensure that notifications are defined somewhere. This can be done globally or at each calendar level.

Global settings are in Thunderbird calendar settings (version 102 here):

[image: Global reminder and notification settings in Thunderbird]

Calendar specific settings are accessible by double-clicking on the calendar :

[image]

Here is how a calendar notification looks like on macOS:

[image: macOS Thunderbird notification for a calendar event]

Here is how a calendar notification looks like in Linux with KDE:

[image: KDE Thunderbird notification for a calendar event]

Comment: This doesn't actually make it use the native notification system, like it does for email notifications. It still uses a custom notification dialog which doesn't integrate with the native system.

Also this solution requires you to set notifications for all events in a calendar instead of individual events (not all events warrants a notification).

Comment: @heksesang I have edited my answer to add screenshots of the notifications, and to me, they clearly use the native notification system. What makes you think that they don't? And yes, you can tweak reminders for each event, but the notifications are defined either per calendar or globally. That's what Thunderbird can do as of today.

Comment: Because I tested it on Windows 11. They do not look like the native notifications, and they do not appear in the notification center. It might be that it uses the native systems on macOS and Linux, but the question was in regards to Windows.