# Write Thunderbird addon to handle Calendar notifications

Tags: add-on, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-lightning

Following [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74920126/13437113) about Thunderbird Calendar popups, I am still looking for a way to display Calendar notifications as "native" Windows 10 system notifications.

Before I invest any time in learning how to write a Thunderbird addon, is it even possible to "listen" to Calendar notifications to "send" them to Windows 10's system notifications?

Sorry in advance if I use inaccurate programming vocabulary.

Thank you in advance!